# Set different Canonical url programmatically for every post

Tags: seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I want to set the set the cannonical url programmatically for every post.

By that I mean when creating/editing an article there should be the possibility to set a custom cannonical url for it. (maybe via custom fields?).

Right now I am using the WP Seo by Yoast as Seo plugin.

Best regards

Comment: under the title, you have the permalink which is editable

Comment: Well, I don't want to change the permalink. Of the article.

Lets assume something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530708/different-canonical-urls-for-facebook-and-google

this is why i want to be able to set the cannonical manually for everypost

Comment: if I understand, you want that different URL show the same post ? where do you want use these different URL ?

Comment: Exactly. I want it exactly like in the link i posted in my other comment "I would like to use (1) as the canonical URL for OpenGraph/Facebook, so if you "like" (2) and (3) then will count for (1).

Answer (score 2):

You can do that programmatically right from inside the plugin's settings by using the `wpseo_canonical` filter.

You can also set it on a per post basis:

[image: Yoast Canonical links settings]

You can even set the canonical links for categories, tags and any taxonomy for that matter as well.
All you have to do is follow instructions at [Canonical URLs in Yoast SEO](http://kb.yoast.com/article/148-canonical-urls-in-wordpress-seo)